# Highest Twin primes such that the number in between twins is the $\text{lcm}$ of first $N$ numbers

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, twin-primes

$\text{lcm}(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) = 420$ and this number is placed between two Twin primes: $419,\ 421$.
This happens again for $\text{lcm}(1,2,3...19) = 232792560$ and
$\text{lcm}(1,2,3,4,...,47)=442720643463713815200$ that is  placed between the 2 Twin primes:
$$442720643463713815199 \\
442720643463713815201$$
However it does not happen again up to where I could reach about $\text{lcm}(1,2,3..., 44983).$

Is $N=47$ the largest number such that $\text{lcm}(1,2,3,...,N)$ is placed between two Twin primes?

I find this huge gap between 47 and, at least, 44983, highly counter-intuitive. There could be a good reason for this.

Complete list :
$$\text{lcm}(1,2,3) = 6 \text{  Twin primes: 5 7}$$
$$\text{lcm}(1,2,3,4) = 12 \text{  Twin primes: 11 13}$$
$$\text{lcm}(1,2,3,4,5) = 60 \text{  Twin primes: 59 61}$$
$$\text{lcm}(1,2,3,4,5,6) = 60 \text{  Twin primes: 59 61}$$
$$\text{lcm}(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) = 420 \text{  Twin primes: 419 421}$$
$$\text{lcm}(1,2,3,...,19) = 232792560 \text{  Twin primes: 232792559 232792561}$$

(then 47 already mentioned above)

I also add a very simple code in python, using the sympy library, so everyone can verify this.

```
    from sympy import *
    
    lcmi=2
    for i in range(3,100000):
        print "Evaluating lcm of first", i, "numbers" 
        ni= lcm(lcmi,i)
        if ni != lcmi:
         if isprime(ni-1) and isprime(ni+1):
            print i,"lcm:", ni,"Twin primes:", ni-1, ni+1
         lcmi=ni
```

Comment: https://oeis.org/A057822 only verified the result up to 2000.

Comment: Thanks a lot @player3236 !

Comment: @rtomas you should list all numbers between $N=1, \dots, 47$ such that it works.  E.g. $\text{lcm}(2,3,4) = 12$  and $\pm 1 = 11,13$.

Comment: excellent suggestion @CommutativeAlgebraStudent , I did so.

Comment: I just found this interesting work: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.6050.pdf  That demonstrates that the number between 2 Twin primes cannot be expressed as as $36ab\pm 6a\pm 6b$, with $a$ and $b$ natural numbers. Maybe the lcm's for N above 47 are always of that form?

Comment: I do not think that we will be able to rule out infinite many twin-primes of this form.We can however find out a heuristic result based on the probability that $n$ is surrounded by a twin-prime pair (here we have to consider that small prime factors are ruled out). Mabye, someone will do this.

Comment: You are right @Peter.  Some suggestions on how to go about your proposal would be welcome.

Comment: For single primes, such heuristics are easier because we can well estimate the effect if small prime factors can be ruled out. I am not sure whether this is also feasible for a pair of numbers with difference $2$ having no small prime factors.

Comment: I made another post for the heuristics: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3956379/correct-reasoning-for-a-finite-number-of-twin-primes-next-to-the-lcm-of-first-n  Also, I have been updating the post with largest N without meeting Twin primes from numerical search from the initially posted N=5000 to the latest one of  N=44983.

Answer (score 2):

Write $a_n := \operatorname{lcm}(1, 2, \ldots, n)$.

When you're looking at $n=7$ you're considering the pair $420\pm 1$.  The form of these numbers excludes the prime factors 2, 3, 5, and 7, and $\sqrt{420} \approx 20.5$, so the only potential remaining prime factors are 11, 13, 17, and 19.

On the other hand, when you're looking at, say, $n = 9$, you're considering $2520\pm 1$, and $\sqrt{2520} \approx 50.2$.  The form of these numbers still excludes only 2, 3, 5, and 7 as prime factors, but now in addition to 11, 13, 17, and 19 you have to worry about 23, 27, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, and 47.

Now $a_n = e^{n + o(n)}$ (see [Chebyshev's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function)), so the number of primes less than $\sqrt{a_n}$ grows faster than linear in $n$, while the number of primes less than $n$ (i.e. the number of primes excluded as factors of $a_n \pm 1$) grows slower than linearly.

As a result, going only by this we'd expect exactly the sort of behavior you see here: true for all sufficiently small $n$, and then sporadically true for a few larger numbers if the pieces fall into place.

Of course that doesn't *prove* anything, but it does tell us that the numerical evidence here isn't pointing towards anything unusual, and therefore likely gives us no help in trying to prove or disprove that there are infinitely many $n$ for which $a_n \pm 1$ are relatively prime.

Comment: right, I made another post with similar arguments: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3956379/correct-reasoning-for-a-finite-number-of-twin-primes-next-to-the-lcm-of-first-n  Actually suggesting that there are only finmite $a_n$ such $a_n\pm1$ are twin primes. What do you think?