# Correct reasoning for a finite number of twin primes next to the lcm of first N numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, twin-primes, chebyshev-function

Does the following argument make sense?

Let ${\rm lcm}(1,...,N)$ be the least common multiple of the first $N$ natural numbers.
In:

[Highest Twin primes such that the number in between twins is the $\text{lcm}$ of first $N$ numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3937771/highest-twin-primes-such-that-the-number-in-between-twins-is-the-textlcm-of)

it is numerically shown that $N=47$ is the largest $N$ such that ${\rm lcm}(1,...,N) \pm 1$ are twin primes, for $N<36000$.

According to Brun's theorem the number of twin primes less than $n$, $\pi_2(n)$, does not exceed the following expression

$$\pi_2(n) < \frac{Cn}{\log^2n} $$

for some constant $C>0$. The ${\rm lcm}(1,...,N)$ can be written as

$${\rm lcm}(1,...,N)=e^{\psi(N)}$$

where $\psi(N)$ is the Chebyshev function that fulfills

$$|\psi(N)-N| = O\left(N^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon}\right)$$

for any $\epsilon > 0$.
Imagine we compute the first N ${\rm lcm}(1,...,j)$ with $j\leq N$, such that $n={\rm lcm}(1,...,N)=e^{\psi(N)}$. The probability $P$ that one of the ${\rm lcm}(1,...,j)$ is between 2 twin primes is as maximum given by

$$P < \frac{\frac{Ce^{\psi(N)}}{\log^2e^{\psi(N)}} }{e^{\psi(N)}}  = \frac{C}{\psi^2(N)} $$

and hence the number of ${\rm lcm}(1,...,j)$ in between twin primes is maximum $N\times P$,

$$ N\times P < \frac{CN}{\psi^2(N)} $$

which in the limit for very large $N$ vanishes,

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{CN}{\psi^2(N)} = 0$$

so in the limit $N\times P=0$, which cannot be consistent with infinite ${\rm lcm}(1,...,j)$ between Twin primes, right?

Note that the same argument for the number of single primes next to ${\rm lcm}(1,...,j)$ is consistent with infinite.

Comment: Your inequality $P < \cdots$ would follow from the Brun sieve bound if $\mathrm{lcm}(1, \dots, j) \pm 1$ were two randomly and independently chosen integers in $[1, e^{\psi(N)}]$.  But they're not; in fact, they're much more likely to be prime than "typical" integers, because they're chosen to be $\pm 1$ modulo many small numbers.

Comment: @RaviFernando , yes, there is partially some truth in what you say but it seems that the lcm advantage becomes negligible after some N. The number of primes below $n$ is $\pi(n)=n/\log n$, so there are $e^{\psi(N)}/\psi(N)$ primes compared to $N/\log(N)$ primes that divide the $lcm(1,...,N$). In relative terms this advantage becomes 0 for large $N$. This seems to arise also from numerical evidence. But yes, putting this in formal math is the challenge.

Comment: I don't think it's really negligible.  An integer that's not divisible by $p_1, \dots, p_n$ is more likely than average to be prime by a factor of $\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{p_i}{p_i - 1}$.  Smaller primes contribute more here, and the product actually diverges as $n \to \infty$.  Granted, it diverges very slowly compared to the denominator $\psi^2(N)$, so at least heuristically I would expect your finiteness claim to be true.

Comment: Maybe the more salient point is this:  the Brun sieve is very good at bounding how many twin primes can occur in a large interval.  But if we focus our attention on a very sparse set of special numbers, the question becomes much harder--and this would be true even for a sparse set of numbers that aren't unusually likely to be prime.

Comment: Proofs of this kind are usually out of reach, but even ruling out many small prime factors makes it difficult to find a twin prime pair, so without having checked the situation numerically, I would intuitively assume finite many such twin primes. But for a careful heuristic argument, we have to consider that both numbers have no small prime factors and have difference $2$, so they are quite related. Not sure which result a careful analysis would give.

Comment: From the numerical side I left my computer run for more days and it reached N=44983 without finding any lcm(1,...,N) in between Twin primes. Maybe N=47 is really the last one...

Comment: @rtomas How large are the two numbers for this $N$ ?

Comment: Hi @Peter, lcm(1,..., 44982) has 19555 digits. It starts with 8108513362747015904807.... and ends with ...2818944000000. Indeed doing the approximation ${\rm lcm}(1,...,N)\approx e^{N}\approx 10^{44982/\ln10} \approx 10^{19535.4...}$, not far from 19555

Comment: @rtomas  To be pedantic , $N=48$ does the job as well giving the same numbers as $N=47$. My doublecheck arrived only at $10^4$ , no further pair found.

Comment: you are absolutely right @Peter! Thanks for the doublecheck!